Is it possible to use MKL static libraries while cross-compilation on arm64 for x86_64?
When I try to cross-compile for macOS on arm64 for x86_64, I have a problem with linking MKL static libraries.

ld: unknown file type in 'libmkl_core.a', 'libmkl_sequential.a',
'libmkl_intel_lp64.a'

version of library 2020.3.279 for Darwin.
I use the same files, that I have used for x86_64 normal compilation.
What files should I use in cross-compilation for x86_64?

The problem is found:
These files was not synced from my git repo using git-lfs.
All their sizes were 1 kb, insted real.
After the downloading, the compilation succeed.
